Is a soybean puree safe to eat if cooked for a constant 195°F, but not heated to boiling?
Trying to use a double boiler to make tofu, but the puree will not exceed 195°F (90°C) in temperature.
Is it absolutely necessary to bring to a boil and if not, how long to cook at 195°F?
